# The Mashing proccess

Tags: fermentation, mash

What is the Mash? Is this the boiling of the grains, Hops and all the Fermentables. If this isn't it please school me up, with the Kiss program. Or in other words keep it simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super simple. You combine hot water and crushed malted barley for about an hour. This turns the starches into sugar that you can collect and later boil for beer.

It's all covered in this [Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashing)

Comment: You earned your points this time.